# AngularJS scope in function does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, factory

I have two ajax calls. The data starts from the html (input), when enter is pressed, what is in the input field is sent to the controller then to the factory which makes the first ajax call. The success is handled back in the controller, then another ajax call is requested, and the data from that request is handled back in the controller again. I have a `$scope` -- `$scope.ytChannel = data.items;` in that final success within the function that does not seem to be working. Here is my code starting with the html

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control channel-index" type="text" ng-model="channel" placeholder="Enter Channel" ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && cname(channel)"/>
```

JS:

```
.factory('ytVids', function($http){

    return{
        getChannel: function(name){
            var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? part=contentDetails&forUsername='+ name +'&key=[my api key]';
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        getVids: function(channel){
            return    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId='+channel+'&key=[my api key]');

        }
    };
  })
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, ytVids) {
     $scope.cname = function(channel){
        ytVids.getChannel(channel).success(function(response){
            //console.log(response);
            console.log(response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);
            ytVids.getVids(response.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log('in success');
                console.log(data.items);
                $scope.ytChannel = data.items; // This is the scope that is not seeming to want to work. 
            });
        });
    };
  });
```

And here is the html that calls that `ytChannel`

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ytChannel" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 vid-options">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="title">{{item.snippet.title}}</div>
      <img src="{{item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url}}" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

if a scope is in a function, does the html not have access to it? What can be done so I can have access to the returned data?

### Error

This is the error the console gives in the dev tools 
 `GET http://localhost:9000/%7B%7Bitem.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is

```
<img ng-src="{{item.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url}}" />
```

As the manual [says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc),

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: that did get rid of the error, and there are no other errors in the console, however none of the data is showing up in my html. Any clue why here?

Comment: Working example on plunker or jsfiddle would help to make this clear. You may check network pane in devtools to see what's going on.